# How can I access to a public final static list declared into an utility class from another class in a Java application?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, static

I have the following doubt. Into a Java application I have an utility class like this:

```
public class CodUtility {

    /* TIPOLOGIA PROGETTO */
    public static final String CODICE_PROGETTO_WIFI = "W";
    public static final String CODICE_PROGETTO_LIM = "L";
    public static final String CODICE_PROGETTO_ALTRO = "A";
    public static final String CODICE_PROGETTO_CLASSI20 = "2";
    public static final String CODICE_PROGETTO_SCUOLA20 = "S";
    public static final String CODICE_PROGETTO_CSD = "C";

    public static final LinkedHashMap<String, String> hashMapDescrizioneTipologiaProgetto = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
    static {
        hashMapDescrizioneTipologiaProgetto.put(CODICE_PROGETTO_WIFI, "WIFI");
        hashMapDescrizioneTipologiaProgetto.put(CODICE_PROGETTO_LIM, "LIM");
        hashMapDescrizioneTipologiaProgetto.put(CODICE_PROGETTO_ALTRO, "Altro");
        hashMapDescrizioneTipologiaProgetto.put(CODICE_PROGETTO_CLASSI20, "Classi 2.0");
        hashMapDescrizioneTipologiaProgetto.put(CODICE_PROGETTO_SCUOLA20, "Scuola 2.0");
        hashMapDescrizioneTipologiaProgetto.put(CODICE_PROGETTO_CSD, "CSD");
    }

    public static final List<String> listaCodiciTipologiaProgetto = new ArrayList<>(hashMapDescrizioneTipologiaProgetto.keySet());
    /* FINE TIPOLOGIA PROGETTO */
}
```

This class define this **public final static** list:

```
public static final List<String> listaCodiciTipologiaProgetto = new ArrayList<>(hashMapDescrizioneTipologiaProgetto.keySet());
```

Now my doubt is: ho can I retrieve it from another class. I need to retrieve this list from another class and access to it.

How can I do this operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to get the list from another object?

`CodUtility.listaCodiciTipologiaProgetto;` Will return the list.